# fail to setup openstack dynamic inventory

Tags: python, dynamic, ansible, openstack, ansible-inventory

I am trying to setup openstack dynamic inventory,when I am trying execute this command it's throwing me this error.

**command:** `etc/ansible/hosts --list`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/ansible/hosts", line 263, in <module>
    main()
  File "/etc/ansible/hosts", line 249, in main
    inventory = shade.inventory.OpenStackInventory(**inventory_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shade/inventory.py", line 35, in __init__
    config_files=os_client_config.config.CONFIG_FILES + config_files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/os_client_config/config.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.cloud_config['clouds'] = {}
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Could you please put your actual command line in your question?

Comment: I have downloaded the actual script from ansible website.This the actual command.   ./openstack.py --list

Comment: Are you using Ansible 2.5? from Ansible 2.5, os_client_config.clouds retuen "[]" as default value but not defined any value prior 2.5.
I wonder if it affects you...

[Ansible 2.5 document: os_client_config](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/os_client_config_module.html?highlight=os_client_config), 

[Ansible 2.4 document: os_client_config](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/os_client_config_module.html)

Comment: I have tested the same script using ansible 2.4 version as well it's throwing me the same error as the one before